# Sitecore Upload File watcher

Tags: file-upload, sitecore

I am using Siteocore 8.1 and have some documents to upload in the system. (heaps of pdf files though each files size not more that 250KB). 
When I have dropped all in sitecore upload directory. Sitecore created folder items in media library but did not uploaded single file inside the folders.
Is anything I am missing here? Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest you easier way to achieve what you want:

1. Zip your PDF files. You can use your folders structure.
2. Upload archived file. Use upload files (advanced) button. Check "Unpack ZIP archives" checkbox.
   [image]
3. It can take some time, depending on the size of the zip file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the FileSystemWatcher’s internalBuffer fills up and starts skipping files. Try to upload 1 or 2 pdf files as a test, and if it is good, you can check with Sitecore Support for the patch 322918.

The patch increases the InternalBuffer to avoid the unexpected skipping of files.

1. Add the string `<add type=”Sitecore.Support.UploadWatcher,Sitecore.Support.322918″ name=”SitecoreUploadWatcher”/>` before each occurrence of the string `<add type=”Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel” name=”SitecoreUploadWatcher”/>`

(see `<system.webServer>/<modules>` section and `<system.web>/<httpModules>` section)

2. Comment out all such lines: `<add type=”Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel” name=”SitecoreUploadWatcher”/>`
3. Put the Sitecore.Support.322918.dll file into the /bin folder of your web site
4. In the web.config file, add the following string under the `<settings>` section

`<setting name=”FileSystemWatcherBufferSize” value=”4096000″/>`

Such value seems to be enough for 5000 files, but you can increase it further to be sure that even files with very long names are uploaded.

More information, please check the link http://www.webdatasource.com/2010/09/sitecore-upload-to-media-library-issueproblem/

**EDIT:**

For Sitecore 8, the `<system.web>/<httpModules>` is not available. You may add the httpModules as follows:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>     
    <add type=”Sitecore.Support.UploadWatcher,Sitecore.Support.322918″ name=”SitecoreUploadWatcher”/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Thanks

Comment: Add the string before each occurrence of the string, I can only find one occurrence of <add type=”Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel” name=”SitecoreUploadWatcher”/> only in system.webserver section. I am using sitecore 8.1 Update 2

Comment: In Sitecore 8, you do not have the `<system.web>/<httpModules>`. Please see my updated answer.